# Bootstrap navbar doesn't behave as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying out the simpliest examples from bootstrap tutorials - page headers, navbar. 
  But while the header works fine, the navbar isn't displayed properly.

I have a `project_name` folder and inside:

```
project_name
        bootstrap
                 css: bootstrap.css, bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap-         
                     responsive.css, bootstrap-responsive.min.css
                 img
                 js: bootstrap.js, bootstrap.min.js, jquery.js

        index.html
```

So, the bootstrap and jquery seem to be in order and the `index.html` code seems to be ok too.

index.html:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Basic Bootstrap Template</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"      
    href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
    <body>
       <!-- HEADER -->
        <div class="page-header">
             <h1 align="center">Some title
             <small>some subtitle</small>
             </h1>
         </div>
         <!-- HAVBAR-->
            <nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse" role ="navigation">

                        <div class="container">
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NAVBAR</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class = "navbar-header">

                                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href = "#">SVN</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
            </nav>


                <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
                <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body></html>
```

It gives:[image: this result]

I can't figure out what's wrong..

I expect to get the similar result (but different text and inverse colors):
[image: result from tutorial]

Comment: the `nav` is supposed to be the first element after `body`

Comment: @isherwood, nope, it doesn't. It complains only about how `align` attribute is obsolete and how `nav` doesn't have a `role` attribute.

Comment: @El Sam, I deleted the header stuff, it didn't change. The navbar looks the same..

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Deke Editted the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in `<div class = "navbar-header">` as it should be associated to the logo not the list.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was in youtube-tutorial of 2014, and it worked for the guy.. The internet is full of misleading code sources..

Comment: It all depends on the bootstrap version you're using, I recommend you always refer to [W3C Bootstrap 3 tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp).

Answer (score 3):

Put Navbar on the top.

Try this:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
       <!-- HEADER -->
       <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NAVBAR</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SVN</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your design to look exactly like the image you have attached, you simply need to exclude this block of code

```
         <div class="page-header">
            <h1 align="center">Some title
            <small>some subtitle</small>
            </h1>
         </div>
```

Excluding this code will give you a UI just like the one in your attached image. For another basic tutorial on navbars, check out this site: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Hope this helps!